# OpenCSV WithVerifier Problem validating fields on the same row

Tags: java, csv, opencsv, read.csv

I'm trying to perform a validation to check if 2 fields informed in the csv exist in the database.

Given the CSV:

```
RECORD_TYPE;COD_NATURE;COD_TAXATION
TEST;100001;12;
TEST;100002;12;
TEST;777777;12;
```

I need to validate line 1 if 10001 and 12 exist in the data list.

However, when validating COD_NATURE = 10001, the tool already discards line 1 and does not validate the COD_TAXATION=12 column.

My Code:

```java
CsvToBean<Layout4010Csv> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder<Layout4010Csv>(
    new FileReader(CSV_FILE_PATH))
        .withSeparator(SEPARATOR)
        .withType(Layout4010Csv.class)
        .withVerifier(new CodNatureVerifier()) //if there is an error here, it already discards the entire line
        .withVerifier(new CodTaxation())
        .withThrowExceptions(false)
        .build();
```

---

```java
public class CodNatureVerifier implements BeanVerifier<Layout4010Csv> {

    @Override
    public boolean verifyBean(Layout4010Csv bean) throws CsvConstraintViolationException {
    
        boolean isCodNatureExists = CodNatureRepository.findById(bean.getCodNature()).isPresent();
    
        if (!isCodNatureExists) {
            throw new CsvConstraintViolationException(bean);
        }

        return true;
    
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class CodTaxationVerifier implements BeanVerifier<Layout4010Csv> {

    @Override
    public boolean verifyBean(Layout4010Csv bean) throws CsvConstraintViolationException {
    
        boolean isCodTaxationExists = codTaxationRepository.findById(bean.getcodTaxation()).isPresent();
    
        if (!iscodTaxationExists) {
            throw new CsvConstraintViolationException(bean);
        }

        return true;
    
    }
}
```

When doing the `csvToBean.getCapturedExceptions()` I can only catch exceptions thrown in the first column which is `CodNatureza` and for the second column `CodTaxation` I can't because the line has already been discarded.

EDIT:
I performed more tests trying to implement a single class called AllVerifier, but I need that every when I call the csvToBean.getCapturedExceptions() method, it has a CsvConstraintViolationException for each column in error.

Attempt 1: if it gives the first error, it doesn't even enter the second condition anymore.

```
    @Override
    public boolean verifyBean(Layout4010Csv bean) throws CsvConstraintViolationException {

    boolean isCodNatureExists = codNatureRepository.findById(bean.getCodNature()).isPresent();

    if (!isCodNatureExists) {
        throw new CsvConstraintViolationException(bean);
    }

    boolean isCodTaxationExists  = codTaxationRepository.findById(bean.getCodTaxation()).isPresent();

    if (!isCodTaxationExists ) {
        throw new CsvConstraintViolationException(bean);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Attempt 2: It even returns that the line is invalid, but it doesn't tell me which fields are invalid, so it doesn't answer.

```
    @Override

    public boolean verifyBean(Layout4010Csv bean) throws CsvConstraintViolationException {

    boolean isCodNatureExists = codNatureRepository.findById(bean.getCodNature()).isPresent();
    boolean isCodTaxationExists = codTaxationRepository.findById(bean.getCodTaxation()).isPresent();

    if (!isCodNatureExists || !isCodTaxationExists) {
        throw new CsvConstraintViolationException(bean);
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this technology but one thing you could possibly try is to validate both fields simultaneously, since that is in any case the requirement of your logic

Comment: Combine the logic in `CodNatureVerifier` and `CodTaxationVerifier` into one class, returning one overall `true` or `false` result based on the two separate checks you need to perform (basically what @g00se says).

Comment: I did but didn't get the expected result.

I need a "throw new CsvConstraintViolationException(bean)" for each error so I can map and save an error log.

Comment: Your comment is new information. You should add these details to the question. Can you also show us your attempt? You can [edit] your question. Also, why do you need to throw exceptions in order to write to a log?

Comment: I'm reading a csv file and I need to inform the user that the data filled in the column is wrong through the log.

I edited the post with the examples I tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this constructor for the constraint violation...

```java
CsvConstraintViolationException(Object sourceObject)
```

...you can use this one:

```java
CsvConstraintViolationException(Object sourceObject, String message)
```

Or even this:

```java
CsvConstraintViolationException(String message)
```

So, for example, you can use `bean.getCodNature()` in one of the message strings, and `bean.getCodTaxation()` in the other one.

---

See the [JavaDoc](https://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/exceptions/CsvConstraintViolationException.html#CsvConstraintViolationException-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-) for more details.